# Refit.ApiException at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization, .net-6.0, refit

I am using Refit to call APIs in .NET 7.0

`System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter` throws exception when the response returned in empty.

It works fine when result contains data.

I think when when result is returned in list it works fine but for empty result {} is unable to being convert into empty array so it fails.

Anyone who could suggest solution ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], at the minimum simplified JSON samples + data model that reproduce the problem.  The full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any, would also help.  See [ask].

Comment: And what kind of collection are you deseralizing?  A `List<T>`?  An array? A jagged 2d `List<List<T>>`?  Something else like an `ObservableCollection<T>`?